# Redirect away from login page if already signed in

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to write a code to redirect users to a specific URL, when the user visits the `loginpage` and is already signed in.

I found a code here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/redirect-if-already-logged-in

Although I dont know how to change the "**`is_front_page()`**" to the login page.
Also, can I insert this in the functions.php?

```
<?php
  if (is_user_logged_in() && is_front_page() ) {
     wp_redirect('domain.com/pageToRedirectTo');
     exit;
  }
?>
```

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: Did you try code which you have shown in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, WordPress doesn't ship with an `is_login_page()` function. However, you can create your own in *functions.php*:

```
function is_login_page() {
    return in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) );
}
```

I would then add the following action hook to *functions.php*:

```
function redirect_logged_in_user() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_login_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/pageToRedirectTo/') ); 
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_logged_in_user' );
```

Read more about the `template_redirect` hook [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).

Comment: Thanks!
I ended up using your solution with a little twist, since my login page is not on the ordinary wp-login.php page, and it works perfectly:

function redirect_logged_in_user() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page( 'login' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/website-url/') ); 
        exit;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy just check first is it a login page and to check for login page you have to use

> $GLOBALS['pagenow']

If yes then check if user is logged in already.

If yes then redirect it.

Your full code will look something like this:

```
if ( in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) ){
   if ( is_user_logged_in()){
        wp_redirect( home_url('domain.com/pageToRedirectTo/') ); 
        exit;
   }
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can put this code to your **login page or in header.php** to redirect logged in user to specific page :

```
<?php 
    if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect (home_url("/yourpage") );
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Unless the OP has implemented a custom login page, adding the code to the login page would involve editing core files...